# Grails RestBuilder query parmeters

Tags: grails

I'm writing some functional tests for a Grails controller, and I feel it's getting messy when testing the query parameters.

I know that I can do this, but it just seems clunky.

```
Map getParms = [id:1, x:foo, y:bar, z:baz]
RestResponse response = builder.get("http://example.com/api/{id}?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}") {
    urlVariables getParams
}
```

Ideally I'd like to:

1. Fill the base URL (i.e. the Id) using the `urlVariables` argument above
2. Pass another map of query params that appends each as a key value pair

Something like:

```
Map queryParms = [x:foo, y:bar, z:baz]
RestResponse response = builder.get("http://example.com/api/{id}") {
    urlVariables id:1
    queryVariables queryParams
}
```

I feel this would be much more 'DRY', and easier to read/write.

Does anyone know if such a mechanism exists? I know I could put together a class to do it, but I was hoping to avoid this if there is an existing implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below.

```
Map queryParams = [x: 'foo', y: 'bar', z: 'baz']
RestResponse response = builder.get("http://example.com/api/{id}", queryParams) {
    urlVariables id:1
}
```

`RestBuilder's` [get()](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-rest-client/src/main/groovy/grails/plugins/rest/client/RestBuilder.groovy#L116) is overloaded to accept three params: String url, Map queryParams and the RequestCustomizer closure

Comment: Thanks for this - but it seems to only replace variables in the URL that are marked as placeholders, not add a query string. I'm hoping to avoid having to set the URL with placeholders, and just throw a map at it. For the moment I've just written a quick method to concat a map into a query string.

Answer (score 1):

I felt the same awkwardness when initially using the API. Currently I'm doing something slightly more concise:

```
RestResponse response = builder.get("http://example.com/api/{id}?x={x}&y={y}", [id:1, x:'foo', y:'bar'])
```

It doesn't feel that bad, kinda same style with named sql parameters in groovy SQL